# How to enable wire logging in Jetty Server

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, jetty

We have a service which uses [Jetty Server](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) 7.6.0

I am trying to enable wire logging by putting following configuration

```
<!-- Configure an appender for the wire log-->
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE">org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.Threshold">TRACE</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.File">${root}/var/output/logs/wire.log</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.DatePattern">&apos;.&apos;yyyy-MM-dd-HH</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.Append">true</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.Encoding">UTF8</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.layout">org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout</prop>
                <prop key="log4j.appender.WIRE.layout.ConversionPattern">%d{DATE} [%p] %X{RequestId} (%t) %c:%m%n</prop>

                <!-- Adjust log levels -->
                <prop key="log4j.logger.WIRE">TRACE, WIRE</prop>
```

When I start the server, wire.log file is getting created but it is not printing anything from my requests into the log file.

I wanted to know is wire logging something specific to Tomcat ? If no , any idea how to enable it in Jetty?

Thanks,

Vishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire logging is an option for apache HttpClient.

Jetty is not using apache HttpClient, but org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient).

Logging http messages in jetty has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735676/jetty-http-logging).

[This](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Request_Logs) may also help you.